# Words are added to the end of a column

Tags: c#, sqlite

In my database, each letter has its own column, but when I add words to the column, it goes to the bottom and Null fields are created

[Now so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NQbC.jpg)

[And I need it this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BLdv.jpg)

I have a list of words and the word must fall into the column from which the first letter of the word begins

My Code

```
  private void ConnectData()
    {
        _path = "URI=file:" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/russianWords.db"; //Path to datab
        _dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(_path);
        _dbConnection.Open();
        if (_dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            m_sqlCmd = new SqliteCommand();
            m_sqlCmd.Connection = _dbConnection;
            m_sqlCmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words (а Text , б Text ,в Text,г Text,д Text,е Text,ё Text,ж Text,з Text,и Text,й Text,к Text,л Text,м Text,н Text,о Text,п Text,р Text,с Text,т Text,у Text,ф Text,х Text,ц Text,ч Text,ш Text,щ Text,ъ Text,ы Text,ь Text,э Text,ю Text,я Text)";
            m_sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        AddToData("sddd", "т");
    }

public void AddToData(string word)
{
    try
    {
        m_sqlCmd.CommandText = $@"INSERT INTO words ('{word.ToCharArray()[0].ToString()}') values ('{ word }')";
        m_sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the result you're trying to get and he result you actually get?

Comment: Can you share the screen shot you've mentioned?

Comment: @Mureinik done I added screenshots and described what I want to do a little more precisely

Comment: Why does AddToData take both the word and the column? If you want the word put in the column whose name is that starting letter of the word, surely you can get this from the word, not need to pass the column too??

Comment: @Caius Jard Ok i fixed

Comment: You can just write `word[0]` instead of `word.ToCharArray()[0].ToString()`. Strings can be treated like char arrays. A char can be put into a string without ToString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases don't work like this. Putting data in a table will always make a new row. It is not like a game of upwards- Tetris where you insert "Fred" into column "F" and it will find the first empty slot (nearest the "top") and put it there. There isn't even the sense of "top" - datatable tables are just a bunch of rows stored in whatever order the database feels like. If you want your data to have an order you must insert some data that has an order (like an int) and sort by it

If you want this "Tetris" style behavior you must program it explicitly. Have a column that is incrementing numbers

```
ID  A  B  C
1
2
```

You want to insert Apple. Select the lowest ID where the column is blank

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM t WHERE A IS NULL
```

ExecuteScalar that and cast the result to an `int?`

If there is an ID, update it. Otherwise insert:

```
UPDATE t SET A = 'Apple' WHERE ID = 1

ID  A      B  C
1   Apple
2
```

Now we want to insert Aeroplane. It will go in ID 2 by the same logic

```
ID  A         B  C
1   Apple
2   Aeroplane
```

Now we insert Aurora. There is no row 3. The SELECT that finds the ID will return no rows (you'll get a null returned from execute scalar)

Run the following insert

```
INSERT INTO t(ID, A)
SELECT MAX(id)+1, 'Aurora' FROM t


ID  A         B  C
1   Apple
2   Aeroplane
3   Aurora
```

You now have aurora in ID 3

Continue thus either inserting or updating. You should thus have at least one column that is completely full all the time and the others will fill in as they go..

--

Consider to use any auto numbering facility your chosen db has rather than max+1 (but max+1 would work)